# Помогите понять суть дженериков в java

Tags: java, generics

прочитал достаточно литературы, но суть дженериков не понял.

1. Мы написали дженерик класс, с полями и методами. Создали объект

   1.1.  Что и когда происходит в процессе компиляции? Стирание типов выполняется сразу и в памяти хранится объект базового типа? Если так, то когда выполняется приведение к нужному типу.

   1.2 При создании объекта генерируется новый класс?

Иными словами проясните плиз процесс компиляции и создания объекта

Answer (score 0):

Новых классов не генерируется. При компиляции проверяется только проверка типов, чтобы выдать ошибку сразу если она есть. В рантайме же все дженерики `T[]` заменяются на `Object[]` и в нужных местах есть каст. Например метод `<T> T get(int i)` в `List<T>` скастует до `T` после выхода из метода.